# Accessing device/emulator file system In Android Studio

Tags: android, ddms

I have a program that saves a .JSON file on the emulator or device I have for debugging my android studio program.  I want to copy that file off of the device but can't seem to find a way to do it.

I know it is reasonably easy in Eclipse but can't find a way to do it in Studio.

Answer (score 15):

#### Android Studio 3.0 and newer versions

1. Select the **Device File Explorer** tab from bottom-right in Android Studio.

[image]

2. Select your emulator.
3. To copy a file from the device, locate the file in the File Explorer and right click on it > Select **Save As**.
4. To copy a file to the device, right click on desired directory > Select **Upload**.

---

#### For older versions of Android Studio

You can import/export files to/from the device.

1. Select the **Devices** tab.

[image]

2. Select your emulator.
3. To copy a file from the device, locate the file in the File Explorer and click the Pull file button.
4. To copy a file to the device, click the Push file button on the File Explorer tab.

Answer (score 4):

In latest Android Studio if the "Device file explorer" is not visible, you can use 
view -> Tool Window -> Device File Explorer

Answer (score 1):

**If you want getting your downloaded file on emulator using download manager.**

**Go To:** **View** > **Tool Window** > **Device File Explorer**

Now You have Watching Lots Of Folder:

Open : **sdcard** > **Download**

Your Downloaded File is Here.

Answer (score 0):

Goto the Android Device Monitor in the android studio and new poup window will open with the devices list in the left pane and in the right pan select the File Explorer Tab and that's it

Original post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32711684/5053350)

Answer (score 0):

Open Android Device Monitor From Android Studio from Icon Or

**Tools>Android>Android Device Monitor**

then click on your running emulator may be

**emulator-5554 or something**

then click on **file explorer**