# Accessing data from device in Android Studio

Tags: android, file, directory-structure

it's my first question here. I searched a lot on the site but didn't find any answer for my question.

Basically, I want to load a directory containing jpeg and mp3 in the tablet and retrieve the path from these files and put them in a SQLite database. I have no trouble using the database but I don't know how to retrieve the paths of the files or even to verify the existence of the directory. Any hint on how to access these files without putting them in the application drawable and sound folder would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Look for the DDMS/monitor button on the top bar, it's near the virtual device manager and the sdk manager.

Comment: Actually that won't help much any more, as for a couple of years of releases now the paths of storage in DDMS (and ADB which gives it this capability) **are different** from those where apps see the same files.  The poster would be better off exploring with a file manager *app*, but best served by using the external storage APIs to discover the applicable path at runtime.

Comment: Thank you, I have been able to get to the root using 

 `dossier=new File("/");
        liste=dossier.list();

        for( int i=0; i<liste.length ;i++){
            Log.i("file path",liste[i]);
        }'`

Answer (score -1):

Goto the **Android Device Monitor** in the android studio and new poup window will open with the **devices** list in the left pane and in the **right pan** select the **File Explorer Tab** and that's it